# Adding the value of session variable to the inner Html of a span tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having trouble writing the C# to dynamically add the value of a session variable into the inner html of a span tag.

This is the particular snippet of HTML in question:

```
<li><strong>You have <span style="background-color:red; color:white; border-radius: 50%; padding: 2px;" id="spanCounter"></span> connections.</strong></li>
```

I was thinking about doing something to the effect of:

```
spanCounter.InnerHtml = Session["Count"].ToString();
```

...but Visual Studio does not detect the span's id. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `runat="server"` to your span tag.